# Can we wrap the column data to fit in the column with xslt?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am transforming data from XML to csv format through xslt and the following is the xslt that is designed.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xsl" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CR_TUAN_HR_-_Goals_Report__Talent_">
  <xsl:output method="text"></xsl:output>
  <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xA;'"></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="comma" select="','"/>
  <xsl:variable name="char-in">"</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="char-out">"</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="Remove">",'</xsl:variable>    
  <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data" >
    <xsl:text>EMPLOYEE_ID,CREATED_ON,DUE_Date,REFERENCE_ID,GOAL_DESCRIPTION
    ,GOAL_DETAILS,GOAL_NAME,WEIGHT</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:EmployeeID"/>
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:CreatedOn"/>
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:DueDate"/>          
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:ReferenceID"/>    
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Description"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$comma" />
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(Description, $char-in, $char-out)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(Description,$Remove,'')">
        </xsl:value-of>
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Detail/@wd:Descriptor"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(Detail, $char-in, $char-out)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(Detail,$Remove,'')"></xsl:value-of>         
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(Name, $char-in, $char-out)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(Name,$Remove,'')"></xsl:value-of>                  
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Weight"/>
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>          
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
        </xsl:for-each> 
       </xsl:template>    
       </xsl:stylesheet>

 Here is my XML input which is causing column breaks which may be due to 
 comma,double quotes,single quotes and some other special characters in 
 description column.

   <wd:Report_Entry>
   <wd:EmployeeID>2839</wd:EmployeeID>
   <wd:CreatedOn>2016-01-29T11:39:00-08:00</wd:CreatedOn>
   <wd:DueDate>2017-06-30-07:00</wd:DueDate>
   <wd:ReferenceID>GOAL-3-54</wd:ReferenceID>
   <wd:Description>
   <p>1. &nbsp;Volunteer for administrative needs solicited by the firm.
   <br>2. 
   Check in with Team Rupp on a monthly basis to see if I can assist team to 
   alleviate their workload.</p><p>3. &nbsp;Mentor De Holden, administrative 
   assistant, in the office to the "Ryan Way" weekly (or as needed). &nbsp; 
   I 
   will train her as my back up for office management to ensure the office 
   runs smoothly in my absence.</p><p>4. &nbsp;Continue to train De Holden, 
   on 
   HotDocs and CRM so she can effectively support her Team Rupp.</p><p></p>
  </wd:Description>
  <wd:Detail wd:Descriptor="Mentor/ Project Work">
  </wd:Detail>
  <wd:Name><p>Mentor/ Project Work</p></wd:Name>
  <wd:Weight>10</wd:Weight>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:EmployeeID>2839</wd:EmployeeID>
  <wd:CreatedOn>2017-07-25T14:16:00-07:00</wd:CreatedOn>
  <wd:DueDate>2017-07-21-07:00</wd:DueDate>
  <wd:ReferenceID>GOAL-3-10548</wd:ReferenceID>
  <wd:Description>
  <p>1. Volunteer for administrative needs solicited by the firm.</p><p>2. 
  Participate in Quarterly Administrative Meetings for updated information 
  and 
  knowledge forums to improve my efficiency.</p><p>3. Check in with Team 
  Rupp, 
  as needed, to assist team to during heavy work times to alleviate some 
  pressure.</p><p>4. Mentor De Holden, administrative assistant, in the 
  office 
  to the "Ryan Way", as needed. I will continue to train her as my back up 
  for 
  office management to ensure the office runs smoothly in my absence.</p>
  <p>5. I will continue to train De on HotDocs, CRM, and the engagement 
  process, as needed.</p>
  </wd:Description>
  <wd:Detail wd:Descriptor="Mentor / Project Work">
  </wd:Detail>
  <wd:Name><h1>Mentor / Project Work</h1></wd:Name>
  <wd:Weight>10</wd:Weight>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:EmployeeID>2576</wd:EmployeeID>
  <wd:CreatedOn>2016-02-05T11:35:00-08:00</wd:CreatedOn>
  <wd:DueDate>2017-10-31-07:00</wd:DueDate>
  <wd:ReferenceID>GOAL-3-395</wd:ReferenceID>
  <wd:Description>
  <p><span>I will coordinate 1 Community Outreach event for the Houston 
  Office.&nbsp; Working with the&nbsp;<span>Manager of Community Outreach 
  and going through the new RyanShares website, I will "Manage an Event" by 
  generating a PO, working with </span></span><span>Casa de Esperanza to 
  </span><span><span>arrange the event, and finally, seeing to its 
  success.&nbsp; Measurement will be based on the event being completed and 
  coming in under budget.&nbsp;&nbsp; </span></span></p>
  </wd:Description>
  <wd:Detail wd:Descriptor="Community Outreach - Houston">
  </wd:Detail>
  <wd:Name><p>Community Outreach - Houston</p></wd:Name>
  <wd:Weight>35</wd:Weight>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:EmployeeID>2086</wd:EmployeeID>
  <wd:CreatedOn>2017-02-10T11:56:00-08:00</wd:CreatedOn>
  <wd:DueDate>2017-06-30-07:00</wd:DueDate>
  <wd:ReferenceID>GOAL-3-7634</wd:ReferenceID>
  <wd:Description>
  <ul><li>Create a new training binder containing material for new 
  consultants. &nbsp;This will include a training agenda, HR documents, etc.
  </li><li>Create a "New hire FAQ's" resource document containing important 
  information needed by new hires that has traditionally been provided only 
  verbally. &nbsp;</li><li>Create a sample client reporting binder as a 
  &nbsp;best practices reference for Group Reports and tax consultants. 
  &nbsp;This will contain a sample report, sample schedules, sample claim 
  packages, etc. and explanatory notes where needed.</li><li>Update old 
  training materials: DW training materials: exercises and sample source 
  docs; file closing process document and flow charts; and file assembly 
  details document.</li></ul><p></p><p>These materials will be made 
  available to the Principal - Canadian Commodity Taxes, Tax Support team, 
  Tax Consultants, and Group Reports team by the end of June 2017.<br>&nbsp;
  </p>
  </wd:Description>
  <wd:Detail wd:Descriptor="Training materials">
  </wd:Detail>
  <wd:Name><p>Training materials</p></wd:Name>
  <wd:Weight>25</wd:Weight>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:EmployeeID>2392</wd:EmployeeID>
  <wd:CreatedOn>2017-07-20T11:26:00-07:00</wd:CreatedOn>
  <wd:DueDate>2017-10-31-07:00</wd:DueDate>
  <wd:ReferenceID>GOAL-3-9595</wd:ReferenceID>
  <wd:Description>
  <p>Develop an "At-A-Glance" Outside Legal Counsel checklist by October 31, 
   2017.&nbsp;</p>
  </wd:Description>
  <wd:Detail wd:Descriptor="Outside Counsel Checklist">
  </wd:Detail>
  <wd:Name><p>Outside Counsel Checklist</p></wd:Name>
  <wd:Weight>40</wd:Weight>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:EmployeeID>6852</wd:EmployeeID>
  <wd:CreatedOn>2017-05-31T10:30:00-07:00</wd:CreatedOn>
  <wd:DueDate>2017-06-16-07:00</wd:DueDate>
  <wd:ReferenceID>GOAL-3-8352</wd:ReferenceID>
  <wd:Description>
  <p>Design, create and implement a tracking matrix (spreadsheet) for 
  "repetitive" tasks (continuous, daily, weekly and monthly), Information 
   Security mailbox and report creation/review. The matrix will indicate 'at 
  a glance' confirmation of security related tasks completion.</p>
  </wd:Description>
  <wd:Detail wd:Descriptor="Tracking Matrix">
  </wd:Detail>
  <wd:Name><p>Tracking Matrix</p></wd:Name>
  <wd:Weight>30</wd:Weight>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:EmployeeID>5120</wd:EmployeeID>
  <wd:CreatedOn>2017-02-06T07:26:00-08:00</wd:CreatedOn>
  <wd:DueDate>2017-06-30-07:00</wd:DueDate>
  <wd:ReferenceID>GOAL-3-5561</wd:ReferenceID>
  <wd:Description>
  <p>Work towards identified 2017 AOP initiatives and deliverables:</p><ul>
  <li>Workday Value Realization: Engage with Workday to complete Workday 
  Value Realization for current functionality use&nbsp;and new enhancements 
  available.</li></ul><p><span class="emphasis">Proposed Goal Change 
  submitted on 5/12:</span></p><p><span class="emphasis">Justification: This 
  goal for 'Workday Value Realization' is being removed for this goal cycle 
  due to higher priority proj<b>ects in Q1 and Q2 based on organization 
  needs. See list of Workday Optimization Projects tracked here (</b>
  </span>\\rfs\Team_HR_Administration\HRIS and 
  Analytics\Projects\2017_HRIS_Workday_Optimization_Tracker.xlsx) <span 
  class="emphasis"><b>by priority. The </b></span><span 
  class="emphasis">Workday Value Realization goal will be part of the 2017 
  Second-Half goals.</span></p><ul><li>New Integrations Development: Bravo 
  (New Wellness Vendor; Outbound and Inbound Integrations), Compass (New 
  Benefit vendor; Outbound Integration) and YourCause (Community Outreach; 
  Outbound and Inbound Payroll Integrations, Outbound HR file Integration)
  </li><li>Submit completed&nbsp;2017 AOP deliverable document as outlined 
  by Jayna Bovre: Complete the&nbsp;HRIS Operations Plan for 2017. The plan 
  will be completed on or before 4/30/2017.&nbsp; This includes:<ul>
  <li>Purpose</li><li>Objectives</li><li>Staffing</li><li>Project Plan – 
  based on 2017 AOP</li><li>Budget recommendations (depends on Finance and 
  resources)</li><li>Attend 1:1 progress meetings as scheduled with Jayna 
  Bovre.</li><li>Draft Plan submitted to Jayna Bovre by 4/15/17 for 
  consolidation and review.</li></ul></li></ul>
  </wd:Description>
  <wd:Detail wd:Descriptor="2017 AOP Deliverables">
  </wd:Detail>
  <wd:Name><p>2017 AOP Deliverables</p></wd:Name>
  <wd:Weight>20</wd:Weight>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:EmployeeID>5120</wd:EmployeeID>
  <wd:CreatedOn>2017-02-06T07:26:00-08:00</wd:CreatedOn>
  <wd:DueDate>2017-06-30-07:00</wd:DueDate>
  <wd:ReferenceID>GOAL-3-5562</wd:ReferenceID>
  <wd:Description>
  <p>Work on identified Workday Optimization Projects (not limited to the 
  following, additional projects of higher priority may replace ones 
  identified below);</p><ul><li>Enhance Workday Onboarding Experience: 
  Configure and implement new enhancements within Onboarding. This includes 
  updates to onboarding from Workday releases 26 &amp; 27 - Changes to 
  Onboarding landing pages and re-structure landing page layout, re-ordering 
  of Onboarding business process steps so its clearer and less confusing to 
  new hires.</li><li>Recruiting Enhancements:&nbsp;1. Start design and 
  configuration for Referral Process in Workday. 2. &nbsp;Begin design and 
  implementation for Agency Management within Workday. Aly Cline 
  (Recruiting) lead on both projects, HRIS to support and provide adequate 
  guidance toward design and implementation.</li></ul><p></p><p><span 
  class="emphasis">Proposed Goal Change submitted on 5/12: Added new 
  additional goal below identified as a significant task for Q1 and Q2 based 
  on data discrepancies identified to ensure consistent data integrity in 
  Workday.</span></p><ul><li><span class="emphasis">Process and Data 
  Enhancements and Data Audit: </span></li></ul><p><span class="emphasis">- 
  Improve Workday business processes related to Hire, Job Change - 
  incorporate data validations where possible within process to ensure data 
  integrity where data is being entered into Workday.</span></p><p><span 
  class="emphasis">- Create organized set of data audit reports to review 
  and identify discrepancies in datasets in Workday where corrections or 
  updates may be needed. Establish periodic schedule and by assigned team 
  members to review data audit reports on a routine basis.</span></p>
  </wd:Description>
  <wd:Detail wd:Descriptor="Workday Optimization Projects">
  </wd:Detail>
  <wd:Name><p>Workday Optimization Projects</p></wd:Name>
  <wd:Weight>30</wd:Weight>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:EmployeeID>5120</wd:EmployeeID>
  <wd:CreatedOn>2017-02-06T07:26:00-08:00</wd:CreatedOn>
  <wd:DueDate>2017-05-31-07:00</wd:DueDate>
  <wd:ReferenceID>GOAL-3-5579</wd:ReferenceID>
  <wd:Description>
  <ul><li>Design, configure and implement&nbsp;<span>2016 Profit Sharing 
  Incentive</span>&nbsp;distribution process within Workday.</li><li>Partner 
  with HRBP, Finance and US Ops teams to define requirements for bonus 
  distribution process, and extract reports to meet business needs to 
  analyze 
  pool allocation and distribution.</li><li>Deploy&nbsp;<span>2016 Profit 
  Sharing Incentive d</span>istribution process in Workday and load final 
  payments for payout.</li></ul><p></p><p><span class="emphasis">Proposed 
  Goal Change submitted on 5/12:</span></p><p><span 
  class="emphasis">Justification: The original goal above has been amended 
  oer the below based on the updated requirements to roll out the incentive 
  award using the GlobalShares tool vs. Workday. Final payout will still 
  take 
  place in Workday.</span></p><ul><li><span 
  class="emphasis">Design/Configure 
  Compensation Plan for payout in Workday and partner with Compensation and 
  Payroll to load test incentive payments in Workday and validate test 
  payout 
  amounts loaded. Load final incentive amounts in Workday.</span></li><li>
  <span class="emphasis">Design/Configure and implement integrations and 
  reports in Workday to support data needs for adequate GlobalShares set up.
  </span></li><li><span class="emphasis">Design, configure and 
  implement&nbsp;2016 Profit Sharing Incentive&nbsp;notification process 
  within Workday for international employees.</span></li></ul>
  </wd:Description>
  <wd:Detail wd:Descriptor="2016 Profit Sharing Incentive">
  <wd:ID wd:type="WID">80ee39b716ae01452d554ff0dd41a85f</wd:ID>
  </wd:Detail>
  <wd:Name><p><span>2016 Profit Sharing Incentive</span></p></wd:Name>
  <wd:Weight>25</wd:Weight>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:EmployeeID>1504</wd:EmployeeID>
  <wd:CreatedOn>2017-02-10T12:01:00-08:00</wd:CreatedOn>
  <wd:DueDate>2017-06-30-07:00</wd:DueDate>
  <wd:ReferenceID>GOAL-3-5017</wd:ReferenceID>
  <wd:Description>
  <p>Manage the process of developing the new version of eReview due to be 
  rolled out to the organization with the Laptop Refresh project in late 
  summer.</p><p>Work with the eReview User group to develop required changes 
  to the program including the development of a new data "view", and the 
  revamp of the exposure module to facilitate reporting.</p><p>Work with the 
  programmer to obtain quotes and approvals for the approved scope of work. 
  Including any follow up questions and development.</p><p>Co-ordinate 
  regression testing of the new version on the new platforms. This step 
  needs to be completed by the end of May.</p><p>Present the initial version 
  to the Tax Consulting group at the June tax meeting.</p>
  </wd:Description>
  <wd:Detail wd:Descriptor="eReview Version 12 Development">
  </wd:Detail>
  <wd:Name><p>eReview Version 12 Development</p><p></p></wd:Name>
  <wd:Weight>40</wd:Weight>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:EmployeeID>6291</wd:EmployeeID>
  <wd:CreatedOn>2016-07-22T11:59:00-07:00</wd:CreatedOn>
  <wd:DueDate>2017-12-31-08:00</wd:DueDate>
  <wd:ReferenceID>GOAL-3-2344</wd:ReferenceID>
  <wd:Description>
  <ul><li>Review open opportunities on a regular basis, drafting emails for 
  Jim to follow up with EP or client</li><li>Review "Open Opportunities" 
  spreadsheet <b><u>within 5 days</u>&nbsp;of receipt of spreadsheet</b>
  </li><li>Update OneNote and CRM with new opportunities based on emails, 
  phone calls, etc.</li><li>Scan JMT's meeting notes and update OneNote and 
  CRM</li></ul>
  </wd:Description>
  <wd:Detail wd:Descriptor="OPPORTUNITY TRACKING">
  </wd:Detail>
  <wd:Name><p><b>OPPORTUNITY TRACKING</b></p></wd:Name>
  <wd:Weight>25</wd:Weight>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:EmployeeID>6098</wd:EmployeeID>
  <wd:CreatedOn>2017-01-31T11:42:00-08:00</wd:CreatedOn>
  <wd:DueDate>2017-06-30-07:00</wd:DueDate>
  <wd:ReferenceID>GOAL-3-5295</wd:ReferenceID>
  <wd:Description>
  <ul><li>Develop, review, and approve&nbsp;2017 roadmap and planning for 
  Career Path and Job Architecture for 2017 deliverables.</li><li>Consult, 
  evaluate, and assist with requirements and deliverables as defined by 
  Sprint Reviews and Sprint Plans. Progress and deliverables are defined in 
  weekly AIP reporting.</li><li>Act as advisor within Core Team based on the 
  future state design and implementation plan; attend meetings, provide 
  research, recommendations, and review/approve deliverables within the 
  deadline. Deliverables are included in the AIP Performance Management plan 
  and approved in Sprint Reviews.</li></ul>
  </wd:Description>
  <wd:Detail wd:Descriptor="Goal #1 Talent Management AIP 2017">
  </wd:Detail>
  <wd:Name>
  <p><b><u>Goal #1 </u></b></p><p><b>Talent Management AIP 2017</b></p>
  </wd:Name>
  <wd:Weight>25</wd:Weight>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:EmployeeID>6098</wd:EmployeeID>
  <wd:CreatedOn>2017-01-31T11:42:00-08:00</wd:CreatedOn>
  <wd:DueDate>2017-06-30-07:00</wd:DueDate>
  <wd:ReferenceID>GOAL-3-5297</wd:ReferenceID>
  <wd:Description>
  <p>ORIGINAL:</p><ul><li>Manage and coordinate the conclusion of the 
  current LDP, as determined by CHRO.</li><li>Coordinate and manage 
  the&nbsp;next phase of Ryan's Leadership Development Program; work with 
  key stakeholders to define expectations and plan.</li><li>Provide the 
  functional framework as determined by key stakeholders.</li><li>Implement 
  program based on the approval and timeline by Leadership.</li></ul><p></p>
  <p><span class="emphasis">INCLUDE ADDITIONAL GOAL #5 AND REVISED 5/16/17:
  </span></p><ul><li>Evaluate and plan “Future Ryan Leaders” strategies to 
  make Principal – (An Executive Leadership Development Program).</li>
  <li>Provide draft framework for Principal Path Program, working with key 
   stakeholders and other resources. Present concept to Leadership for 
   future program guidance.</li></ul>
  </wd:Description>
  <wd:Detail wd:Descriptor="Goal # 4 Leadership Development (Developing 
  Leaders) ADDED GOAL #5 WITH REVISIONS - 5/16/17">
  </wd:Detail>
  <wd:Name>
  <p><b><u>Goal # 4</u></b></p><p><b>Leadership Development (Developing 
  Leaders)</b></p><p></p><p><span class="emphasis"><b>ADDED GOAL #5 WITH 
  REVISIONS - 5/16/17</b></span></p>
  </wd:Name>
  <wd:Weight>30</wd:Weight>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:Report_Entry>
  <wd:EmployeeID>6098</wd:EmployeeID>
  <wd:CreatedOn>2017-01-31T11:42:00-08:00</wd:CreatedOn>
  <wd:DueDate>2017-06-30-07:00</wd:DueDate>
  <wd:ReferenceID>GOAL-3-5298</wd:ReferenceID>
  <wd:Description>
   <p>ORIGINAL GOAL #5</p><ul><li>Evaluate and plan “Future Ryan Leaders” 
  strategies to make Principal – (An Executive Leadership Development 
  Program).</li><li>Coordinate and work with key stakeholders to define 
  expectations and strategy.</li><li>Provide Proof of Concept framework as 
  determined by key stakeholders.</li><li>Implement program based on the 
  approval and timeline by Brint Ryan.</li></ul><p></p><p><span 
  class="emphasis">MOVED TO GOAL #4 AND REVISED</span></p>
  </wd:Description>
  <wd:Detail wd:Descriptor="Goal # 5 Leadership Development Program 
  (Principal Path) GOAL #5 COMBINED WITH GOAL #4 - 5/16/17">
  </wd:Detail>
   <wd:Name>
   <p><b><u>Goal # 5 </u></b></p><p><b>Leadership Development Program 
   (Principal Path) </b></p><p></p><p><span class="emphasis"><b>GOAL #5 
   </b>COMBINED WITH GOAL #4<b> - 5/16/17</b></span></p><p></p>
   </wd:Name>
   <wd:Weight>0</wd:Weight>
   </wd:Report_Entry>

 Here is the Sample desired output for few rows of above XML input

 **EmployeeID** - 2839
 **ReferenceID** - GOAL-3-54
 **Description** - 1.Volunteer for administrative needs solicited by the
```

firm.2.Check in with Team Rupp on a monthly basis to see if I can assist 
  team to alleviate their workload.3.Mentor De Holden,administrative 
 assistant, in the office to the Ryan Way" weekly (or as needed).I will 
  train her as my back up for office management to ensure the office runs 
  smoothly in my absence.4.Continue to train De Holden on HotDocs and CRM 
  so she can effectively support her Team Rupp.

```
**EmployeeID** - 2839
**ReferenceID** - GOAL-3-10548
**Description** - 1. Volunteer for administrative needs solicited by the
```

firm.2. Participate in Quarterly Administrative Meetings for updated 
  information and knowledge forums to improve my efficiency.3. Check in with 
  Team Rupp, as needed, to assist team to during heavy work times to alleviate 
  some pressure.4. Mentor De Holden, administrative assistant, in the office 
  to the Ryan Way" as needed. I will continue to train her as my back up for 
  office management to ensure the office runs smoothly in my absence.5. I will 
  continue to train De on HotDocs, CRM, and the engagement process as needed.

```
**EmployeeID** - 2576
**ReferenceID** - GOAL-3-395
**Description** - I will coordinate 1 Community Outreach event for the
```

Houston Office.Working with the Manager of Community Outreach and going 
  through the new RyanShares website, I will Manage an Event" by generating a 
  PO, working with Casa de Esperanza to arrange the event and finally seeing 
  to its success. Measurement will be based on the event being completed and 
  coming in under budget.

```
**EmployeeID** - 2086
**ReferenceID** - GOAL-3-7634
**Description** - Create a new training binder containing material for new
```

consultants.This will include a training agenda, HR documents, etc.Create a 
 New hire FAQ's" resource document containing important information needed by 
 new hires that has traditionally been provided only verbally.Create a sample 
 client reporting binder as a best practices reference for Group Reports and 
 tax consultants.This will contain a sample report sample schedules, sample 
 claim packages,etc. and explanatory notes where needed.Update old training 
 materials: DW training materials: exercises and sample source docs; file  closing process document and flow charts; and file assembly details 
document.These materials will be made available to the Principal - Canadian  Commodity Taxes, Tax Support team, Tax Consultants  and Group Reports team  by the end of June 2017.

```
**EmployeeID** - 5120
**ReferenceID** - GOAL-3-5561
**Description** - Work towards identified 2017 AOP initiatives and 
deliverables:Workday Value Realization: Engage with Workday to complete 
Workday Value Realization for current functionality use and new enhancements 
available.Proposed Goal Change submitted on 5/12:Justification: This goal 
for 'Workday Value Realization' is being removed for this goal cycle due to 
higher priority projects in Q1 and Q2 based on organization needs. See list 
of Workday Optimization Projects tracked here 
(\\rfs\Team_HR_Administration\HRIS and 
Analytics\Projects\2017_HRIS_Workday_Optimization_Tracker.xlsx) by priority. 
The Workday Value Realization goal will be part of the 2017 Second-Half 
goals.New Integrations Development: Bravo (New Wellness Vendor; Outbound and 
Inbound Integrations),Compass (New Benefit vendor; Outbound Integration) and 
YourCause (Community Outreach; Outbound and Inbound Payroll 
Integrations,Outbound HR file Integration) Submit completed 2017 AOP 
deliverable document as outlined by Jayna Bovre: Complete the&nbsp;HRIS 
Operations Plan for 2017. The plan will be completed on or before 4/30/2017. 
This includes Purpose Objectives Staffing Project Plan based on 2017 AOP 
Budget recommendations (depends on Finance and resources Attend 1:1 progress 
meetings as scheduled with Jayna Bovre.Draft Plan submitted to Jayna Bovre 
by 4/15/17 for consolidation and review.

 **EmployeeID** - 5120
**ReferenceID** - GOAL-3-5562
**Description** - Work on identified Workday Optimization Projects (not 
limited to the following, additional projects of higher priority may replace 
ones identified below);Enhance Workday Onboarding Experience: Configure and 
implement new enhancements within Onboarding. This includes updates to 
onboarding from Workday releases 26 & 27 - Changes to Onboarding landing 
pages and re-structure landing page layout, re-ordering of Onboarding 
business process steps so its clearer and less confusing to new 
hires.Recruiting Enhancements:1. Start design and configuration for Referral 
Process in Workday. 2. Begin design and implementation for Agency Management 
within Workday. Aly Cline (Recruiting) lead on both projects, HRIS to 
support and provide adequate guidance toward design and 
implementation.Proposed Goal Change submitted on 5/12: Added new additional 
goal below identified as a significant task for Q1 and Q2 based on data 
discrepancies identified to ensure consistent data integrity in 
Workday.Process and Data Enhancements and Data Audit: - Improve Workday 
business processes related to Hire, Job Change - incorporate data 
validations where possible within process to ensure data integrity where 
data is being entered into Workday.Create organized set of data audit 
reports to review and identify discrepancies in datasets in Workday where 
corrections or updates may be needed. Establish periodic schedule and by 
assigned team members to review data audit reports on a routine basis.

 **EmployeeID** - 6098
**ReferenceID** - GOAL-3-5295
**Description** - Develop, review, and approve 2017 roadmap and planning for 
Career Path and Job Architecture for 2017 deliverables.</li><li>Consult, 
evaluate, and assist with requirements and deliverables as defined by Sprint 
Reviews and Sprint Plans. Progress and deliverables are defined in weekly 
AIP reporting.Act as advisor within Core Team based on the future state 
design and implementation plan; attend meetings, provide research, 
recommendations, and review/approve deliverables within the deadline. 
Deliverables are included in the AIP Performance Management plan and 
approved in Sprint Reviews.Goal #1 Talent Management AIP 2017

**EmployeeID** - 6098
**ReferenceID** - GOAL-3-5297
**Description** - ORIGINAL:Manage and coordinate the conclusion of the 
 current LDP, as determined by CHRO.Coordinate and manage the next phase of 
Ryan's Leadership Development Program; work with key stakeholders to define 
expectations and plan.Provide the functional framework as determined by key 
stakeholders.Implement program based on the approval and timeline by 
Leadership.INCLUDE ADDITIONAL GOAL #5 AND REVISED 5/16/17:Evaluate and plan 
Future Ryan Leaders strategies to make Principal (An Executive Leadership 
Development Program).Provide draft framework for Principal Path 
Program,working with key stakeholders and other resources. Present concept 
to Leadership for future program guidance.Goal # 4 Leadership Development 
 (Developing Leaders)ADDED GOAL #5 WITH REVISIONS - 5/16/17"
```

If XSLT removes all these HTML tags and ignores commas in description 
column, I believe data will not break and move into other columns.

Thanks,
Jithen.

Comment: The input XML has not been shared to find out the issue. Please check the contents of the input XML for the field which is breaking. It may contain certain characters which when transformed using the above XSLT is causing them to break into new line.

Comment: Hi Aniket, Thanks a lot for your prompt response on this. Yes i observed double quotes(") in the data of description column is causing most of the column data to break and flow into new line.But when you see my xslt i have defined to variables to remove the character's,But somehow seems it is not working. Is there any function or template through which all the special characters can be removed and avoid the data from the column's to break into new line ??

Comment: Also comm(,) in the description is causing the column breaks mostly. is there any specific function that removes double quotes(") and comma(,) ? I think if xslt can be able to handle these two special characters, columns will not breaking up.

Comment: Please share sample input XML and the desired output text which would help to provide proper guidance.

Comment: I have added sample XML input ,sample actual output and desired output in text. Request for inputs that resolves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the input XML provided, here is the XSL that will provide the `comma` separated output as shown. The below XSL should provide the desired output.

**XSL**

```
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xsl"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/FR_TRUN_HR_-_Goals_Report__Talent_">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xA;'" />
    <xsl:variable name="comma" select="','" />
    <xsl:variable name="replace" select="''" />
    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
        <xsl:text>EMPLOYEE_ID,CREATED_ON,DUE_DATE,REFERENCE_ID,GOAL_DESCRIPTION,GOAL_DETAILS,GOAL_NAME,WEIGHT</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed" />
        <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry">
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:EmployeeID" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$comma" />
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:CreatedOn" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$comma" />
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:DueDate" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$comma" />
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:ReferenceID" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$comma" />
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(normalize-space(wd:Description), $comma, $replace)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$comma" />
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:Detail/@wd:Descriptor" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$comma" />
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(wd:Name)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$comma" />
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:Weight" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output Text**

```
EMPLOYEE_ID,CREATED_ON,DUE_DATE,REFERENCE_ID,GOAL_DESCRIPTION,GOAL_DETAILS,GOAL_NAME,WEIGHT
2839,2016-01-29T11:39:00-08:00,2017-06-30-07:00,GOAL-3-54,1. Volunteer for administrative needs solicited by the firm. 2. Check in with Team Rupp on a monthly basis to see if I can assist team to alleviate their workload. 3. Mentor De Holden administrative assistant in the office to the "Ryan Way" weekly (or as needed). I will train her as my back up for office management to ensure the office runs smoothly in my absence. 4. Continue to train De Holden on HotDocs and CRM so she can effectively support her Team Rupp.,Mentor/ Project Work,Mentor/ Project Work,10
2839,2017-07-25T14:16:00-07:00,2017-07-21-07:00,GOAL-3-10548,1. Volunteer for administrative needs solicited by the firm. 2. Participate in Quarterly Administrative Meetings for updated information and knowledge forums to improve my efficiency. 3. Check in with Team Rupp as needed to assist team to during heavy work times to alleviate some pressure. 4. Mentor De Holden administrative assistant in the office to the "Ryan Way" as needed. I will continue to train her as my back up for office management to ensure the office runs smoothly in my absence. 5. I will continue to train De on HotDocs CRM and the engagement process as needed.,Mentor / Project Work,Mentor / Project Work,10
2576,2016-02-05T11:35:00-08:00,2017-10-31-07:00,GOAL-3-395,I will coordinate 1 Community Outreach event for the Houston Office. Working with the Manager of Community Outreach and going through the new RyanShares website I will "Manage an Event" by generating a PO working with Casa de Esperanza to arrange the event and finally seeing to its success. Measurement will be based on the event being completed and coming in under budget.,Community Outreach - Houston,Community Outreach - Houston,35
2086,2017-02-10T11:56:00-08:00,2017-06-30-07:00,GOAL-3-7634,Create a new training binder containing material for new consultants. This will include a training agenda HR documents etc. Create a "New hire FAQ's" resource document containing important information needed by new hires that has traditionally been provided only verbally. Create a sample client reporting binder as a best practices reference for Group Reports and tax consultants. This will contain a sample report sample schedules sample claim packages etc. and explanatory notes where needed. Update old training materials: DW training materials: exercises and sample source docs; file closing process document and flow charts; and file assembly details document. These materials will be made available to the Principal - Canadian Commodity Taxes Tax Support team Tax Consultants and Group Reports team by the end of June 2017.,Training materials,Training materials,25
2392,2017-07-20T11:26:00-07:00,2017-10-31-07:00,GOAL-3-9595,Develop an "At-A-Glance" Outside Legal Counsel checklist by October 31 2017.,Outside Counsel Checklist,Outside Counsel Checklist,40
6852,2017-05-31T10:30:00-07:00,2017-06-16-07:00,GOAL-3-8352,Design create and implement a tracking matrix (spreadsheet) for "repetitive" tasks (continuous daily weekly and monthly) Information Security mailbox and report creation/review. The matrix will indicate 'at a glance' confirmation of security related tasks completion.,Tracking Matrix,Tracking Matrix,30
5120,2017-02-06T07:26:00-08:00,2017-06-30-07:00,GOAL-3-5561,Work towards identified 2017 AOP initiatives and deliverables: Workday Value Realization: Engage with Workday to complete Workday Value Realization for current functionality useand new enhancements available. Proposed Goal Change submitted on 5/12: Justification: This goal for 'Workday Value Realization' is being removed for this goal cycle due to higher priority proj ects in Q1 and Q2 based on organization needs. See list of Workday Optimization Projects tracked here ( \\rfs\Team_HR_Administration\HRIS and Analytics\Projects\2017_HRIS_Workday_Optimization_Tracker.xlsx) by priority. The Workday Value Realization goal will be part of the 2017 Second-Half goals. New Integrations Development: Bravo (New Wellness Vendor; Outbound and Inbound Integrations) Compass (New Benefit vendor; Outbound Integration) and YourCause (Community Outreach; Outbound and Inbound Payroll Integrations Outbound HR file Integration) Submit completed2017 AOP deliverable document as outlined by Jayna Bovre: Complete theHRIS Operations Plan for 2017. The plan will be completed on or before 4/30/2017. This includes: Purpose Objectives Staffing Project Plan – based on 2017 AOP Budget recommendations (depends on Finance and resources) Attend 1:1 progress meetings as scheduled with Jayna Bovre. Draft Plan submitted to Jayna Bovre by 4/15/17 for consolidation and review.,2017 AOP Deliverables,2017 AOP Deliverables,20
5120,2017-02-06T07:26:00-08:00,2017-06-30-07:00,GOAL-3-5562,Work on identified Workday Optimization Projects (not limited to the following additional projects of higher priority may replace ones identified below); Enhance Workday Onboarding Experience: Configure and implement new enhancements within Onboarding. This includes updates to onboarding from Workday releases 26 & 27 - Changes to Onboarding landing pages and re-structure landing page layout re-ordering of Onboarding business process steps so its clearer and less confusing to new hires. Recruiting Enhancements:1. Start design and configuration for Referral Process in Workday. 2. Begin design and implementation for Agency Management within Workday. Aly Cline (Recruiting) lead on both projects HRIS to support and provide adequate guidance toward design and implementation. Proposed Goal Change submitted on 5/12: Added new additional goal below identified as a significant task for Q1 and Q2 based on data discrepancies identified to ensure consistent data integrity in Workday. Process and Data Enhancements and Data Audit: - Improve Workday business processes related to Hire Job Change - incorporate data validations where possible within process to ensure data integrity where data is being entered into Workday. - Create organized set of data audit reports to review and identify discrepancies in datasets in Workday where corrections or updates may be needed. Establish periodic schedule and by assigned team members to review data audit reports on a routine basis.,Workday Optimization Projects,Workday Optimization Projects,30
5120,2017-02-06T07:26:00-08:00,2017-05-31-07:00,GOAL-3-5579,Design configure and implement 2016 Profit Sharing Incentive distribution process within Workday. Partner with HRBP Finance and US Ops teams to define requirements for bonus distribution process and extract reports to meet business needs to analyze pool allocation and distribution. Deploy 2016 Profit Sharing Incentive d istribution process in Workday and load final payments for payout. Proposed Goal Change submitted on 5/12: Justification: The original goal above has been amended oer the below based on the updated requirements to roll out the incentive award using the GlobalShares tool vs. Workday. Final payout will still take place in Workday. Design/Configure Compensation Plan for payout in Workday and partner with Compensation and Payroll to load test incentive payments in Workday and validate test payout amounts loaded. Load final incentive amounts in Workday. Design/Configure and implement integrations and reports in Workday to support data needs for adequate GlobalShares set up. Design configure and implement2016 Profit Sharing Incentivenotification process within Workday for international employees.,2016 Profit Sharing Incentive,2016 Profit Sharing Incentive,25
1504,2017-02-10T12:01:00-08:00,2017-06-30-07:00,GOAL-3-5017,Manage the process of developing the new version of eReview due to be rolled out to the organization with the Laptop Refresh project in late summer. Work with the eReview User group to develop required changes to the program including the development of a new data "view" and the revamp of the exposure module to facilitate reporting. Work with the programmer to obtain quotes and approvals for the approved scope of work. Including any follow up questions and development. Co-ordinate regression testing of the new version on the new platforms. This step needs to be completed by the end of May. Present the initial version to the Tax Consulting group at the June tax meeting.,eReview Version 12 Development,eReview Version 12 Development,40
6291,2016-07-22T11:59:00-07:00,2017-12-31-08:00,GOAL-3-2344,Review open opportunities on a regular basis drafting emails for Jim to follow up with EP or client Review "Open Opportunities" spreadsheet within 5 days of receipt of spreadsheet Update OneNote and CRM with new opportunities based on emails phone calls etc. Scan JMT's meeting notes and update OneNote and CRM,OPPORTUNITY TRACKING,OPPORTUNITY TRACKING,25
6098,2017-01-31T11:42:00-08:00,2017-06-30-07:00,GOAL-3-5295,Develop review and approve2017 roadmap and planning for Career Path and Job Architecture for 2017 deliverables. Consult evaluate and assist with requirements and deliverables as defined by Sprint Reviews and Sprint Plans. Progress and deliverables are defined in weekly AIP reporting. Act as advisor within Core Team based on the future state design and implementation plan; attend meetings provide research recommendations and review/approve deliverables within the deadline. Deliverables are included in the AIP Performance Management plan and approved in Sprint Reviews.,Goal #1 Talent Management AIP 2017,Goal #1 Talent Management AIP 2017,25
6098,2017-01-31T11:42:00-08:00,2017-06-30-07:00,GOAL-3-5297,ORIGINAL: Manage and coordinate the conclusion of the current LDP as determined by CHRO. Coordinate and manage thenext phase of Ryan's Leadership Development Program; work with key stakeholders to define expectations and plan. Provide the functional framework as determined by key stakeholders. Implement program based on the approval and timeline by Leadership. INCLUDE ADDITIONAL GOAL #5 AND REVISED 5/16/17: Evaluate and plan “Future Ryan Leaders” strategies to make Principal – (An Executive Leadership Development Program). Provide draft framework for Principal Path Program working with key stakeholders and other resources. Present concept to Leadership for future program guidance.,Goal # 4 Leadership Development (Developing    Leaders) ADDED GOAL #5 WITH REVISIONS - 5/16/17,Goal # 4 Leadership Development (Developing Leaders) ADDED GOAL #5 WITH REVISIONS - 5/16/17,30
6098,2017-01-31T11:42:00-08:00,2017-06-30-07:00,GOAL-3-5298,ORIGINAL GOAL #5 Evaluate and plan “Future Ryan Leaders” strategies to make Principal – (An Executive Leadership Development Program). Coordinate and work with key stakeholders to define expectations and strategy. Provide Proof of Concept framework as determined by key stakeholders. Implement program based on the approval and timeline by Brint Ryan. MOVED TO GOAL #4 AND REVISED,Goal # 5 Leadership Development Program    (Principal Path) GOAL #5 COMBINED WITH GOAL #4 - 5/16/17,Goal # 5 Leadership Development Program (Principal Path) GOAL #5 COMBINED WITH GOAL #4 - 5/16/17,0
```

Comment: Thanks Aniket for your response, When i have used the above XSLT i was getting blank data in description and Name columns.Also similarly can we avoid double quotes and single quotes with XSLT ?

Comment: Please share your input XML containing `double quotes` and `single quotes`. For `<wd:Name>` and `<wd:Description>`, there is `<p>` tag in the shared sample input XML that is actually holding the value. You are getting blanks because the input XML that you are trying does not have the `<p>` tags. If you want the correct XSL, you need to either share the exact input XML or a sample matching the input data with all possible scenarios.

Comment: Hi Aniket, Please find my updated XSLT with which maximum percentage of column breaking is reduced,However there are above 11 rows which are still breaking and when i have seen the output, I have seen after comma rest of the data is breaking and moving into next column.If XSLT can hold of these 11 rows and avoid data breaking into other columns, I think whole issue will be resolved.So please find the updated XSLT and the XML input of the 11 rows which are breaking. Thanks again for all your support and assistance on this.

Comment: The input XML is not well-formed XML. There are missing tags in it. Please correct the input XML. Also the data is breaking because of the `html` tags viz. `<p>`, `<br>`, `<ul>`, `<li>`, etc. in the `<wd:Description>` node. The `<wd:Description>` does not have consistent child nodes and has a varying list of `html` tags. Please ensure the input XML has consistent data across the nodes.

Comment: Aniket, The xml input is auto generated and somehow XML is converting spaces in description column into these html tags.Is there anyway that xslt can remove these html tags and transform output ??

Comment: Can you share the desired output considering the multiple bulleted items in the `<wd:Description>` as to how they will be concatenated to each other?

Comment: Aniket, I have given the desired output of few rows from the above given XML input for the Description column. If XSLT handles html tags and comma's which are causing the column data breaking, I believe this issue can be resolved.Hence would appreciate for any inputs or any corrective directions that resolves this issue.

Comment: I have modified the XSLT in the answer to cater to the desired output. All the concerned `html` inside the `<wd:Description>` and `<wd:Name>` has been handled to provide the proper CSV output. The output has also been shared.

Comment: Aniket, I am still seeing the column break in the csv output file for all the above employee's even after using the enhanced xslt that you have shared and really confused after seeing the output that you have got and the output that i am getting with column breaks. And not sure how to show you the csv output file that is generated with this transformation.

Comment: The output shared in the solution can be verified [here](http://xsltransform.net/3MvmrAd). Please check if the line breaks in the CSV is due to the `commas` already present in the `<wd:Description>` and `<wd:Name>` nodes.

Comment: Yes Aniket the line breaks are due to comma in description column,Ex- Continue to train De Holden,on HotDocs and CRM so she can effectively support her Team Rupp. So after comma line is breaking into next column.Also i am still seeing the tags populating which is not a issue but line breaking is a issue.Seems normalize space is working as required.

Comment: I have modified the solution and the output to replace the `comma` in the `<wd:Description>` tag with an empty string. In case you need some other delimiter, you can modify the value of `<xsl:variable name="replace">` with some other value. I believe you can now tweak the solution according to your additional requirements.

Comment: Aniket, i believe it is working.Thanks a lott, I have used translate function for  description,detail and name columns as if i use this translate function only for description,There is breaking in detail and name columns,So i have used translate in all these three columns and now there is no column breaking nor row breaking happening.but in Weight column few values are placing in special characters. Ex-  ,10" .Can we use only replace function to remove these special characters in weight column ??Thanks a lott again for your continuous support on this.

Comment: Instead of `replace` function, use `translate` as it can handle multiple characters but you need to be careful. You can read more on `translate` on the internet. Also if the solution has worked, please accept the provided answer.

Comment: Appreciate if you can accept the solution provided by me.